# URL should hit https instead of http

Tags: ssl, redirect, iis, https, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running a **Windows Server**, where i have hosted a site.

Now i have done the Binding with the SSL certificate for the site. But every time i hit the website URL, it goes to http instead of https. Althoough i have binded http & https with the SSL certificate.

Example -

when i try to hit abc.com

```
it goes http://example.com
```

instead of

```
https://example.com
```

Do i have to do anything more which can help me to fix this issue.
so everytime i try to visit

```
example.com
```

i will visit

https://example.com

Do anyone knows a way to fix this issue !

Comment: You have many ways to control that, but first, `example.com` by default should go to `http://example.com`, which is a rule from early HTTP days. The answer belows shows how to force redirection to HTTPS, and you might also check out HSTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a redirect to make sure all traffic gets redirected, something like below. Make sure you have the URL rewrite [module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed.

```
<rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```